# Where to stop while caching Bitmap objects into memory in Android?

Tags: android, caching, bitmap

I have a ListView which shows many bitmap images (thumbnails) (downloaded, resized, 70% compressed jpeg)

I use a memoryCache to stop reading files from disk.

```
private static HashMap<String,Bitmap> memoryCache
```

I have another function to clear the cache according to the byte count in it.
But where should i stop? What should be the bytes limit for the cache? Even it is thumbnail, (as it is Bitmap object) it quickly fills the memory.

Comment: check out [Android Universal ImageLoader](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) It is a library that will handle all of the caching for you when loading images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [LruCache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html) to implement this. The docs include a great example, exactly for bitmap cacheing.

Note that the Android Support Package includes this class if you're targeting 2.x.

Comment: In that example i see 4 MiB, it is a good value? Low? High? How to determine that value and can i (should i) dynamically calculate it accoridng to current device's per-app memory limit etc? If yes, how can i do that? This is the real question i am looking for the answer :|

Comment: I use a %age of the heap size, obtainable via http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getMemoryClass%28%29